# why commands in command line starting with python is not working and giving output "Python"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, command-line, powershell-2.0

When I'm running a command starting with python in Windows PowerShell I always have just output "Python"
Example:

```
PS C:\Users\----\Django\jobapp> python -m venv env
Python
```

Example 2:

```
PS C:\Users\----\Django\jobapp> python manage.py runserver
Python
```

I had a python version 3.9 and then I tried to reinstall python for a new version(3.12), but nothing have changed.
I also try to use `python3 -m venv env` or `py -m venv env`, but still no changes

Comment: Maybe the paths to the python installations have not been added to PATH in your environment variables? Run `$env:PATH` in PowerShell to see if it contains the path pointing to where you installed python

Comment: @dan-kli i have added them manually because pip command wasn't working, but it didn't change this problem

Comment: Run this `Get-Command python` to see what command you're actually running.

Comment: @JohnGordon 
Application     python.exe                                         0.0.0.0

Comment: `Get-Command python` should also show you from where you are the python.exe running in `Source`. Is that the path where you installed it?

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding a new path in environment variables. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this as an answer, as @Cow recommended. The problem was that the python exe that Anon tried to run was missing in the environment variables. As @John Gordon pointed out, running the following command in PowerShell will show which `python` is actually getting executed:

```
Get-Command python
```